I am getting error in importing logistic regression in jupyter notebook
error iris flower classification
I am building a classification model for Iris flower classification by using Logistic Regression. I am using jupyter notebook and I am importing Logistic Regression by from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression. The following import error pops up. I tried installing scipy library but the cannot be solved.

Please include error messages as code in the message (using proper formatting), not as screenshots

Welcome to SO; please do not post screenshots of code or error messages - see how to create a [mre].

What's the output of import sklearn ; print(sklearn.__version__)?

If there were to be a subtle misspelling error, including characters that may look the same as another character, it would be impossible for us to find it because we can't copy verbatim the text from your image.

Try re-installing scikit-learn making sure you are in the same environment you are running jupyter
Inside jupyter, go to: file -> new -> Terminal and write
pip install -U scikit-learn

